# How to shift side-by-side box?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying for hours now do to this

[image: pic]

and I can do that slightly shifted box at the left, and because of this I can't put the image above properly either. I keep deforming the website, or have stacked boxes... I tried with position:absolute, with float, and basically everything I know, but I can't seem to get it right. 
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @snoof, this can be solved with flexbox. That guide on css-tricks is very useful, definitely give it a read.

I tried to create your layout, hopefully this can help you understand how to solve it. Warning, this code is not pretty.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RjLVWE

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="left">
        <div id="circle-1" class="circle">
            <div class="circle-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-1" class="box">
            <div class="box-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div id="box-2" class="box">
            <div class="box-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="circle-2" class="circle">
            <div class="circle-inner"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="box-3" class="box">
            <div class="box-inner"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper,
.left,
.right {
    display: flex;
}

.left,
.right {
    position: relative;
}

.left {
    width: 20%;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.right {
    width: 80%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-basis: auto;
}

.box,
.circle {
    padding: 1em;
}

.box {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.box-inner {
    background-color: #000;
}

.circle-inner {
    padding: 7em;
    background-color: #aaa;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

#box-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#circle-2 {
    align-self: flex-end;
}

#box-1 .box-inner {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#box-2 .box-inner {
    padding: 10em;
}

#box-3 {
    width: 100%;
}

#box-3 .box-inner {
    padding: 20em;
}
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I'm gonna read the link with more attention. The circles are meant to be images, and I had trouble puttin them correctly into the page, but I think I'll figure it out now. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the question but to position your boxes, you also can use flexbox :

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Really easy to use and keep a responsive design.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not from a English-speaking country so my English in kinda bad. Thanks for the link, but I don't see how I can use flex to do the left box a bit offset..?